# Electric Shock at 5V and 40 A

Tags: voltage, led, current, insulation

I am using an array of WS2812 leds for an application of mine. The length used is around 10 m with 60 leds/m. The current for one led is 40 mA, this makes the total current to be around 25 A. I wanted to know if this is a dangerous current at 5 volts. I want to know this as I have to put my circuit in an insulation class where a single fault would result in electrical shock to the user.

Comment: With respect to insulation, only voltage is relevant.

Comment: @Rev1.0, unless you're able to run enough current that the wire get hot.

Comment: I am using wire of high gauge 14 AWG, so hopefully that covers it.

Comment: 14 AWG is not necessarily enough for 25A. This depends on the ventillation available.

Comment: If you use the standard WS2812B strips, keep in mind that the strip itself probably isn't rated for 25A! So you can't use one 10m strip only connected at the end(s). Connect multiple shorter strips in parallel.

Comment: The current of one led is a maximum of 60 mA (3 · 20 mA!), not 40 mA.

Comment: @Jeroen3: True, but that is a different aspect. Since OP asked about insulation class, the the current doesn't really matter. I could also state that ambient temperature is relevant because it can cause the wires to get too hot, but that wasn't on the topic ;)

Comment: I see people have mentioned the current to be 60 mA,it is mentioned on data sheet, but that happens when I drive the three leds (R, G, B) to full white. Otherwise average is around 40 mA.

Comment: You **do not** want to deliver 25A (or more) over simple cable at 5 V. if the cabling + connections only have a resistance of 0.1 Ω, you'd drop 2.5 V over that – half your supply voltage. The LEDs won't work, and things will get very warm. It'll be way easier to split things into shorter, galvanically independent runs of LEDs (you can use an optocoupler to daisy-chain the logic signals for the LEDs, if you desire to do so) and supply them from multiple, smaller power supplies (which will  be cheaper, easier to debug and less of a fire hazard)

Comment: @ArjunSingh well, your devices need to not see a voltage dropout in a peak situation. So, knowing the average is nice, but not sufficient.

Comment: I am planning to split the entire 10 m strip into strips of 1.5m length and then power them individually.

Comment: so, then you don't use a supply that can source 40A at all, and your question doesn't describe your situation?!

Comment: I am planning to do that now that people have raised concerns I meant

Comment: ah, ok :) that clears that up :)

Comment: It can certainly not electrocute you. But 40A can produce harmful heat and maybe even fire hazard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 5 V is far underneath the standard hazardous voltage levels (50 Vac, 120 VDC) and far below anything that can cause harm.

This low voltage is insufficient to push a harmful current through dry skin. So if that's their only point of contact, you're OK.

However, it depends where you're planning to deploy this as to how far you have to insulate it and protect from contact. 5 V @ 25 A is more than enough to hurt the user if they put the wires in their mouth. Consider this if, for instance, the wires on your lights are accessible to a baby crawling on the floor, such as with decorative lights.

Comment: 5V wires in the mouth will sting a bit, but it is a common way to quick test a 9V battery. OTOH, 5V at 25A shorting across your metal fillings is going to be a unique experience

Comment: @DirkBruere, nope it will hurt a lot more than that. I thought the 9 V battery would come up - it sounds like you haven't tried a 9 V adaptor, try it now. As a young kid, I tested loads of 9V batteries on my tongue and it tingled nicely. One day I tried it on a 9 V 200 mA adaptor and got far more punch than I ever want again. Teaches you the difference between voltage and current :-) OP's got 25 A.

Answer (score 4):

A 5V 40A power supply can output enough power to make fire hazard a possibility if a short circuit happens at the end of thin wires which are not able to carry the full current without overheating. Fuses rated to protect the wires solve this problem.

This is important if you have connectors which will be handled by the user and other places where shorts can happen.

Comment: I hope, if I use a high gauge wire such as 14 AWG, this issue gets covered or should I take some protective measure even after that.

Comment: @ArjunSingh as a minimum, you need some kind of current limiting.  If the power supply doesn't do that for you, you'd need a suitable fuse.

Comment: It's the same problem as distributing power in a house: you have a source capable of very high current, but each distribution circuit must be protected by a fuse or breaker corresponding to what this circuit can handle. Fuses/breakers protect wires and connectors (sockets) against overheating and fire.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the question straight: no, under normal circumstances. Having a PS that can deliver 25A with output set at 5V does not mean that it will deliver the 25A. If this is going to be a commercial product you should give it more thought, since users can do surprising things.
Anyways, from the WS2812 datasheet (http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/WS2812.pdf) it is seen that the current needed for the LED is 20mA, not 40. Also, you must add a resistor to each led to set the proper current.

Comment: No, you don't need resistors, because WS2812B LEDs have a controller built-in. Also the LEDs are RGB and run on a max current of 20mA _per LED_, which means 60mA per unit.

Comment: True that, I missreaded the datasheet. Thanks for pointing out.